# How should you properly report a beta Flutter issue with beta version 0.8.2?

Tags: dart, flutter

I just updated to Flutter verison 0.8.2 via Flutter upgrade and updated my dependencies and I get a compile time error in media_query.dart. Here's the version info:

```
Flutter 0.8.2 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5ab9e70727 (13 days ago) • 2018-09-07 12:33:05 -0700
Engine • revision 58a1894a1c
Tools • Dart 2.1.0-dev.3.1.flutter-760a9690c2
```

I'd like to report this to the Flutter team, what's the best way to do this?

Here is my actual error:

```
I/flutter (19370): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (19370): The following _CompileTimeError was thrown building WidgetsApp-[GlobalObjectKey
I/flutter (19370): _MaterialAppState#b6c28](dirty, state: _WidgetsAppState#48dc8):
I/flutter (19370): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart': error: line 67 pos 47:
I/flutter (19370): file:///Users/pbirdsall/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:67:47:
I/flutter (19370): Error: The getter 'boldText' isn't defined for the class 'dart.ui::AccessibilityFeatures'.
I/flutter (19370): Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
I/flutter (19370): 'boldText'.
I/flutter (19370):       boldText = window.accessibilityFeatures.boldText,
I/flutter (19370):                                               ^
I/flutter (19370):       boldText = window.accessibilityFeatures.boldText,
I/flutter (19370):                                               ^
I/flutter (19370):
```

Comment: Try `git clean -xfd` `flutter doctor` in your Flutter install directory first. I doubt this is a Flutter issue. Also if you created

Comment: You are probably correct, all of a sudden it stopped occurring and I did not actually report the issue.

Comment: I got interrupted and forgot to complete the sentence. I wanted to say: Also if you created an issue, please add the link to your question.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To submit issues go to the Flutter github repository and look under the tab 'issues'
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues

Check if your particular issue hasn't been brought to the developers' attention already by another user, if it hasn't you can follow the submission guidelines found here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md